# Magento2.4: Category page , if salable qty is 0 , show label on product

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

How to display a label on a product if the saleable quantity is zero with the code?

Comment: are there any other approaches, like plugins or observers?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override this file

```
/var/www/html/new_spectrum/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

in your theme Module_Catalog/view/product/list.phtml

This answer is useful

```
  <?php $objectManager =
     \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $StockState =
     $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku');
     $qty = $StockState->execute($_product->getSku()); 
     $sale_qty = $qty[0]['qty'];
     if($sale_qty == 0) {    
       echo "Do your code" ; 
  }
```

Comment: implemented but not working